# python regex to exclude multiple words

Tags: python

I need to parse a file like this:

```
Nmap scan report for pc15393.foster.xxx.com (192.168.2.211)
Nmap scan report for lab-776.foster.xxx.com (192.168.2.212)
Nmap scan report for 78T458Y.foster.xxx.com (192.168.2.213)
```

I'd like to get rid of "Nmap scan report for" and get the following:

```
pc15393.foster.xxx.com (192.168.2.211)
lab-776.foster.xxx.com (192.168.2.212)
78T458Y.foster.xxx.com (192.168.2.213)
```

If I use the following regex: `extract = re.findall (r'for.*',line)`
I get everything starting from "for" but that's wrong.
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks a lot
Knud

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Clearly replace my_file.txt with your file. This was python 2.7.12

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import re
pattern = re.compile("Nmap scan report for (.*)")
for i, line in enumerate(open('my_file.txt')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only this data, better use awk.

```
cat yourfile | awk '{print $5 $6}'
```

If give information you want.